# Sending location data from android app to apache server

Tags: java, php, android, apache, http

I have created an app that takes the current location of the phone and then should send it to an apache web server.  I'm using a php file on the server to receive the data and then write it to an HTML file. The domain works fine, and it properly displays the html file that I have on the web server, but the php file does not write the data to the html file and I'm not sure why.

Here is the code for sending the data

```
 if (currentLocation == null) {
                                return;
                            } 
else {

       //Creating strings for the latitude and longitude values of our current location
       String latitude = new String(" " + (Math.round(currentLocation.getLatitude()*10000000))/10000000);
       String longitude = new String(" " + (Math.round(currentLocation.getLatitude()*10000000))/10000000);

       // Creating an http client and http post object in order to interact with server
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://findmylocation.chandlermatz.com/");
       try {

      //Creating identifier and value pairs for the information we want to send to server
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Latitude", latitude));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Longitude", longitude));

      //Sending data to server via http client
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
      httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                } 
      catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                } 
      catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

And here is my php code

```
<?php
// get the "message" variable from the post request
// this is the data coming from the Android app
$latitude = $_POST["Latitude"];
$longitude = $_POST["Longitude"];
// specify the file where we will save the contents of the variable message
$filename="index.html";
// write (append) the data to the file
file_put_contents($filename,date('m/d/Y H:i:s') . " &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp" . $latitude . " &nbsp " . $longitude . "<br />",FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is PHP throwing any errors if you turn on error reporting and visit the URL in your web browser?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, the only errors that are in the error logs are Undefined index: Latitude in /var/www/html/locationData.php on line 4 and Undefined index: Longitude in /var/www/html/locationData.php on line 5

Comment: Are those errors present just from you visiting the URL in your browser or do Android attempts cause them as well?

Comment: I see. As a test you should assign `$latitude` and `$longitude` to use static variables and remove `$_POST` completely. Visit the URL using your web browser and see if the static variables are being written to the file. There could be some sort of weird restrictions on your server that could prevent PHP from modifying an HTML file, expecially index.html. You can try using test.txt instead or something.

Comment: You're right, it is not writing to the html file even with static variables

Comment: That will be a permissions issue. Try to generate a html file that does not yet exist. If that also fails you have to change permissins for the root dir completely.

Comment: For more debugging you can try `if(file_put_contents($filename,date('m/d/Y H:i:s') . " &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp" . $latitude . " &nbsp " . $longitude . "<br />",FILE_APPEND) === FALSE){ echo 'This failed?'; }else{ echo 'success!'; }`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus So I tried just echoing the latitude and longitude variables in the php code, but that didn't display anything either when I tried to access it in my browser. Also, when I first restart the sapache service, it prints out the date and time to the html file even if I'm not sending data from the android app

Comment: I assume you're visiting `http://findmylocation.chandlermatz.com/locationData.php`?

Comment: Then what do you get in your browser? So only echo, nothing else. Don't create the file.

Comment: I can see date/time is being written when I visit `http://findmylocation.chandlermatz.com/locationData.php` followed by `http://findmylocation.chandlermatz.com/index.html`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes, that is where I am going.

Comment: The browser test is working for me so I am not sure why it fails for you.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I found the problem. I mistyped the httppost object in my java code and did not put locationData.php at the end of the URL.

Comment: Yep, that would do it!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Always seems to be the simple things I accidentally overlook that cause the most problems

Comment: The devil is always in the details with programming but now that I think about it programming is 100% details so programming must be the devil! Wake up people, 9/11 was staged! j/k and good luck!